# Break at some point in Struts2 Iterator

Tags: java, loops, struts2

I have nested iteration in Struts2:

```
<s:iterator var="gift" value="user.gift">
    <s:iterator value="giftItems">
        <s:property value="type"/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

I want to have up to 10 `type` only. How to break at some point in Struts2 Iteration? I can have a counter variable, but don't know to break in iteration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the begin and end attributes if you know when to break out before begining the iteration. If the break has to be calculated within the iteration, set a variable and check its value using  each time before doing the iteration. In the later case, the loop will technically not 'break', but the effect would be the same.

```
<s:set var = "breakLoop" value = "%{false}" />
<s:iterator....>
<s:if test = "!#breakLoop">
     //process here and change the var to true based on some codition
    <s:set var = "breakLoop" value = "%{true}"/>
</s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: sorry, i am new to this forum and trying to figure out how to post.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't break. Your iteration will continue until the end of the List.

But (if you don't choose to limit the List from Java side, before reaching the JSP),

you can use the `index` (0-based) or `count` (1-based) property of the `StatusIterator` object provided by the `<s:iterator />` to limit the rendering to ten elements:

To limit to 10 types *per giftItem*:

```
<s:iterator var="gift" value="user.gift">
    <s:iterator value="giftItems" status="ctr">
        <s:if test="#ctr.index < 10">
            <s:property value="type"/>
        </s:if>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

To limit to 10 types *at all* (as requested in comments):

```
<s:set var="rowPrinted" value="0"/>
<s:iterator var="gift" value="user.gift" >
    <s:iterator value="giftItems" >
        <s:if test="#rowPrinted < 10">
            <s:property value="type"/>
            <s:set var="rowPrinted" value="%{#rowPrinted + 1}"/>
        </s:if>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

As you can see, you can simply declare a 0-based variable, check it to be under the limit, then increment it (as you would do in Java).

Comment: thanks... but from your solution maybe I'm not clear enough. It should be `10` types at all, so maybe I should use another variable for the `if` test.

Comment: I've edited accordingly to your comment, feel free to test the second solution...